# Obtain XML entity replacement text from DOM in Xerces

Tags: java, xml, dom, entities, xerces

The Javadoc for [`org.w3c.dom.Entity`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Entity.html) states:

> XML does not mandate that a non-validating XML processor read and process entity declarations made in the external subset or declared in parameter entities. This means that parsed entities declared in the external subset need not be expanded by some classes of applications, and that the replacement text of the entity may not be available. When the [replacement text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204#intern-replacement) is available, the corresponding Entity node's child list represents the structure of that replacement value. Otherwise, the child list is empty.

Whilst it does not refer to entity declarations made in the internal subset, there must surely be some configuration of parser which will read and process entity declarations in either subset?  Indeed, my reading of the documentation would suggest that this is the default.

In any event, I have tested the following approach (using Xerces) against entities which have been declared in the internal subset (as shown) and also in an external subset, but `foo.hasChildNodes()` returns false (and `foo.getChildNodes()` returns `foo`!) in every case:

```
// some trivial example XML
String xml = "<!DOCTYPE example [ <!ENTITY foo 'bar'> ]>\n<example/>";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

// parse
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
DocumentType docType = builder.parse(is).getDoctype();

// retrieve the entity - works fine
Entity foo = (Entity) docType.getEntities().getNamedItem("foo");

// now how to get the entity's replacement text?
```

No doubt I am missing something rather obvious; grateful for your thoughts.

---

**EDIT**

It appears from the answers so far that my Xerces implementation is misbehaving.  I will try to update all Xerces libraries to latest versions and, if that solves my problem, I will close off the question.  Many thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Updating Xerces has indeed solved the problem, provided that the entity is referenced from within the document; if it is not, then the node still has no children.  It is not entirely clear to me why this should be the case.  Grateful if someone could explain what's going on and/or point me to how I can force the creation of the child nodes without explicitly referencing every entity from within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the Xerces-J Users mailing list about the non-existence of child nodes where the entities are not referenced within the document; there [Michael Glavassevich helpfully pointed me](http://markmail.org/message/kfxvgrmkcjzytmwk) towards [an old post from Andy Clark](http://markmail.org/message/oq3g26f3t2rbafdv) explaining as follows:

> Unfortunately (for you) this is a feature. And it was implemented
>   this way mainly for performance reasons. If an entity is never
>   referenced in the document, then we never have to waste time
>   reading it. If the external entity is huge but never referenced,
>   we don't waste time or memory.
>
> Plus, there is a deeper problem in relation to namespaces. DOM
>   can't even help. I'll explain...
>
> Take the following document and external entity:
>
> ```
>   <!-- entity.ent -->
>   <hello/>
>
>   <!-- document.xml -->
>   <!DOCTYPE root [
>   <!ENTITY entity SYSTEM 'entity.ent'>
>   ]>
>   <root>
>     <sub xmlns='foo'> &entity; </sub>
>     <sub xmlns='bar'> &entity; </sub>
>   </root>
> ```
>
> Notice that the default namespace is different at each point
>   where the entity is referenced. This means that the 
>   element will be bound to different namespaces. So both
>   instances of the same entity are actually different elements!
>
> In this situation, what should the Entity node in the DOM doctype
>   return: children in the "foo" namespace or children in the "bar"
>   namespace?
>
> In short, it's a complicated issue.
>
> You might be best off trying to read the document fragment
>   yourself when you look for the Entity node and it has no
>   children. Xerces has a document fragment scanner in the impl
>   package that would be useful for this purpose. You'd have to
>   write code that builds children for a DOM document fragment
>   from XNI methods, though. But this isn't hard to do. I can
>   point you to an example if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mistaken how the replacement text works. Based on some reading (http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=entities.sql&id=18238), it looks to me like the replacement text works like a variable. So, in your example above you are never referencing the `&foo;` entity. If you run the code sample below you will see that what happens is the `&foo;` gets replaced with the string `bar`:

```
// some trivial example XML
String xml = "<!DOCTYPE example [ <!ENTITY foo 'bar'> ]><example><foo>&foo;</foo></example>";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

// parse
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
DocumentType docType = doc.getDoctype();

// retrieve the entity - works fine
Entity foo = (Entity) docType.getEntities().getNamedItem("foo");
for(int i = 0; i < foo.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(foo.getChildNodes().item(i));
}
```

What you see printed is `[#text: bar]` which is the text replacement within the XML.

Comment: Sadly, this is exactly what _isn't_ working for me—even if I reference &foo; from within the document (although I completely agree that that's what it _should_ be doing according to the docs).  In my case `foo.getChildNodes() == foo`!  `.getLength()` and `.item(0)` return `0` and `null` respectively.  What implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6.0_20 and using the `org.w3c.dom.Entity` class from there. You cut and pasted the code from above and nothing was printed to the console?

Comment: Indeed.  `foo.getChildNodes().getLength()` returns `0` and so the loop is never entered and `System.out.println` is never called.

Comment: I am using Xerces 2.8.1 - which version are you using because it prints `[#text: bar]` for me?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think Entity nodes store replacement text as text value, and not as set of nodes; this because entities are not actually fully parsed when parsing entity definitions: this mostly since DTD handler is sort of pre-processor that occurs before actual parsing process.
So check out text value of entity node instead of children node list.

Comment: I _think_ the text content of an Entity node _should_ be its "literal value" (i.e. the exact text contained in the entity's declaration); whereas I'm after the "replacement text" (i.e. after character and parameter references have been replaced).  In any event, see my comment to [mzjn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115972/obtain-xml-entity-replacement-text-from-dom-in-xerces/6117085#6117085): it's returning an empty string for me in any case!

Comment: Right, former I would expect to be correct. But latter I would not expect to be true; although I guess it'd be good to read DOM specification. Either way it is rather tricky to expose anything DTD-related since it is quite different from "regular" XML handling, what with different syntax, and being completely regular text replacement, with absolute no structural awareness.

Comment: Thanks; the [relevant bits](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-527DCFF2) of the DOM specification (from which the Javadoc quoted in my question was extracted) explicitly links to the definitions in the XML specification; there it quite specifically distinguishes between "literal entity value" and "replacement text" as above.  However, I think for Entity nodes the text content is defined to be the aggregation of the text content of its children anyway, so it may well be what I need after all.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `foo.getChildNodes()` doesn't work, but I discovered the following. If the entity is used (referenced) in the document,

`<!DOCTYPE example [<!ENTITY foo 'bar'>]>\n<example>&foo;</example>`,

then the replacement text is available via

`foo.getTextContent()`

Comment: Sadly, for me, `foo.getTextContent()` is returning the empty string `""` even if &foo; is referenced within the document.  What parser implementation are you using?

Comment: Also see my comments in response to [StaxMan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115972/obtain-xml-entity-replacement-text-from-dom-in-xerces/6117082#6117082): I believe the text content and replacement text are not quite the same thing.